# Definite article in phrases

Tags: sentence-construction, definite-article

> 1) In the first few weeks, when I was new to **the project**, I made a lot of mistakes.
>
> 2) In the first few weeks, when I was new to computer (or computers?), I made a lot of mistakes.

Is the second example with "new to computer" correct? if yes can I say:

> 3) In the first few weeks, when I was new to **project**, I made a lot of mistakes.

if not, why the second example is correct but the third is not, is there a general rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"New to computer" and "new to project" are incorrect. You could be new to **computers**, in which case you are new to all computers, or you could be new to **the** computer, meaning this specific computer you are working on. You could even be new to **a** computer, meaning that you are new to a specific computer, but you are not saying which one. That would be strange, but I don't see anything grammatically wrong with it.

In your first sentence, that is correct because the speaker is new to the specific project he or she is talking about, and may or may not be new to projects in general. It would be a little odd to say one is "new to projects" since most activities people do can be considered projects, but someone who does not have much experience with computers could definitely say they are "new to computers".

### Edited to add

As the other answer pointed out, in the case of computers the gerund is also acceptable: "new to **computing**". But this is only true because a "computer" is "something that computes". A "project" is not "something that projects", and therefore "new to projecting" is incorrect. It might mean that you are new to speaking loudly to an audience, or new to using a projector to display images on a screen, but not that you are "new to working on projects", which would be the correct form.

Comment: Thank you, then you mean I never can use *computer* as a generic term, in an idiom or something?

Comment: I can't think of any example where you would. Generic concepts are usually going to be plural or take an article. I only say "usually" because all English rules have exceptions, not because I can think of any for this one.

Answer (score 3):

> New to computer

and

> new to project

Neither is correct.

The noun must be in the plural to express the idea of a *domain*: *new to computers.*  Either that, or an `ing` form to express a general type of activity: *new to computing*.

The definite article is used to refer to a specific project: *new to the project*.

Comment: If I say the sentence (1) to a stranger who don't know about any project I do, what *the project* refers to for him? can I say such sentence to him?

Comment: You are engaged in a conversation with him, presumably, so he does indeed know what you're talking about, from *context*. If you walk up to a stranger and say "I'm new to the project", he will assume the project is one that lets the insane walk freely around the city, to see how they do.

Comment: You mean I always can say such sentence? can you  imagine a situation where I can't?

Comment: Can I imagine a situation where you could not say "I'm new to the project"? Yes, I can. It's any situation where your conversation partner has no idea what project you are talking about.

Comment: in the situation you described, If I only want to say him just that phrase, I should say *when I was new to **a** project*? what if I want to continue later to add which project, can I begin with that sentence?

Comment: Use the indefinite article and then switch right over to the definite:  "I was once on *a* scientific project. *The* project involved the study of the effects of mercury on Baltic seabirds."

Comment: Sorry I ask much, does it depends on the word too?, for example in the said situation can I begin with *In the first days, when I was new to the job, I had a lot of mistakes*. as the hearer can imagine anyone has a job?!

Comment: If you are *engaged in a conversation*, and use a phrase like "When I was new to the job" your conversation partner will attempt to make sense of your statement, in light of contextual clues, and is likely to assume you mean your *present* job. But if you haven't been speaking about your jobs, or about something that could at least segue to a discussion of your job, then your conversation partner might think it a *non sequitur* and be momentarily unsure what you were talking about. Substituting "my" for "the" would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general in English, you need an article -- "a" or "the" -- whenever you use a singular noun that is not a proper name. There are some pronouns you can use instead of an article, like "one" or "some". You CAN use "the" with a plural if you want to specify a specific group, but normally you do not.

Examples:

"I was new to the computer." Speaking of one particular computer. Article required. Singular, article required.

"I was new to computers." Speaking of computers in general. Plural, so no article.

"I was new to the computers." Speaking of one specific set of computers, perhaps those of a certain type or owned by this company.

"I bought one computer." Singular so an article would normally be required, but we use the adjective "one" instead.

Comment: Then can I say *I was new to two computers which were bought recently*

Comment: @Ahmad: Not usually, no. Note that *X is new **to** A* essentially means ***from A's point of view,** X is new* (i.e. - *A has only recently encountered X*). Idiomatically we often switch the "perspective" - for example, *I'm new to marriage* (I haven't been married long). But that's essentially a "figurative" usage (the state of "marriage" has no consciousness, so it can't really "experience" you being in that condition). The figurative usage tends to breaks down if ***A*** is a very specific "real-world entity" such as one or two particular computers that have never "met" anyone at all.